# Nth order difference and Nth difference

Tags: python, time-series, arima

In  ARIMA/SARIMA  one parameter id "d", which specifies difference. For differencing when d>1, I have heard two expressions: "n differencing", "n-order differencing". Are these two expressions referring to the same thing?

For example, for 2nd order difference, I have seen the following formula:

```
  yt − 2yt−1 + yt−2
```

What would be the 2nd difference formula (d=2)? Is this the same as previous formula? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression model of ARIMA has the following formula:
[image: ARIMA formula]

The formula of SARIMA is the ARIMA's formula with extra:
[image: SARIMA formula]

As you see there are no **d** and **D** in these formulas. But why do we need them?

ARMA models work a lot better when the time series is stationary. And to make a time series stationary we can differentiate them. If **D** or **d** is more than 1, then we subtract its shifted version from the series.

So, if *d = 1*:

```py
y = y - y.shift(1)
```

If *d = 2*:

```py
y = y - y.shift(1)
y = y - y.shift(1)
```

If *D = 1*:

```py
y = y - y.shift(S)
```

... and so on, where *y* is your time series and *S* is your seasonality period.

P.S. `shift` function is a function of `pandas.Series`, if you don't use pandas you can shift it in your way.